# « adouber » un objet en tant que qqc (d'autre qu'un chevalier) ?

Tags: sens, histoire, synonymes

On [apprend](https://fr.news.yahoo.com/grand-jour-l-hermione-met-cap-lam%C3%A9rique-053014867.html) que l'[*Hermione*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermione_%281779%29) a quitté l'[Île d'Aix](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8Ele-d%27Aix) (dép. Charente-Maritime) en direction de [Yorktown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Yorktown), VA (É.-U.). Dans l'article on peut lire que :

> L'"Hermione", réplique du navire qui emmena en 1780 [La Fayette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_du_Motier,_Marquis_de_Lafayette) se
>   battre aux côtés des "Insurgés" américains contre l'Angleterre, a
>   appareillé samedi soir pour les Etats-Unis, **adoubée** par François
>   Hollande et Barack Obama en tant que symbole de plus de deux siècles
>   d'"amitié franco-américaine".
>
> [ Régine LAMOTHE, AFP – sam. 18 avr. 2015 ]

D'aucuns sont familiers avec le verbe *adouber* aux échecs (toucher une pièce pour la remettre correctement en place). Il y a aussi d'autres acceptions: *réparer* (aussi [*radouber*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/radouber)) en contexte maritime; et, en particulier, le terme d'histoire féodale *armer quelqu'un chevalier*, etc. Une remarque indique:

> *Rem. gén.* 1. Malgré la diversité des domaines dialectaux où il est fait usage de *adouber*, on y trouve toujours le sens de *accommoder*,
>   *raccommoder*, *mettre en état*. 2. Attesté ds *Mots rares* 1965, ce mot, comme tout arch., peut être employé de nos jours de façon iron.
>   ou fam. pour exprimer l'action de se préparer, de s'apprêter (*cf*.
>   aussi La Châtre t. 1 1865, p. 101).
>
> [ *Trésor informatisé de la langue française* - TLFi - « [*adouber*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/adouber) » ]

Mais est-ce qu'on « *adoube* (un bâtiment naval) en tant que » quelque chose d'autre qu'un chevalier, comme un symbole en l’occurrence ? Est-ce courant, qu'est-ce qu'on entend exactement ici par « adoubée », et peut-on présenter un synonyme plus usuel pour aider à la compréhension ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ici « adouber » est utilisé au sens figuré, inspiré du sens d'adouber un chevalier.

Un bon synonyme serait peut-être « reconnu » ou « désigné ».

Une paraphrase explicative serait : « ils ont fait du bateau un symbole de ... » ou : « ils ont vu dans le bateau un symbole de ... ».

Mais cette utilisation d'adouber est loin d'être commune, c'est plus une figure de style ad hoc.

Comment: Merci! « une figure de style ad hoc » en effet! Le choix de « adouber » est particulièrement recherché et judicieux à mon avis, et soutenu par un ensemble de sens qui réfèrent aussi à l'objet etc.

Answer (score 1):

Working backwards from a list of synonyms for "[dubbed](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dubbed)" in English, I totally agree with Alex Halm that “reconnu” and “désigné” would be the best synonyms for “adoubé” in this context (where the designation is not an actual symbolic name/nickname, but rather a multi-word description of what is being symbolized)(but see hypothetical below).

Although not on the linked list, “appointed” and “proclaimed” are two other words that can capture, at least for me, the meaning of “dubbed” in English, so perhaps their French equivalents (“[nommé](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/nomm%C3%A9+en+tant+que.html)” and “[proclamé](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=proclam%C3%A9%20en%20tant%20que),” respectively) could also be given consideration as suitable synonyms for “adoubé” in this context where two heads of state are involved (with the understanding that using "nommé" would probably require the personification of *l'Hermione* as kind of an "Ambassadress of Good Will").

(Just a hypothetical aside, but had the designation been an actual nickname created to symbolize the >200-year friendship [“Deux Siècles d'Amitié,” as one lame example], and not a multi-word description thereof, then perhaps “adoubé” could have been seen and used as a more formal/solemn way of saying “surnommé.” [BTW, we live less than 20 minutes from Yorktown and have enjoyed the annual "[Yorktown Victory Celebration](http://www.historyisfun.org/yorktown-victory-center/yorktown-victory-celebration/)" for years, including the Bicentennial Celebration in 1981 when [President Mitterrand](http://www.nytimes.com/1981/10/20/world/reagan-and-mitterrand-observe-200th-anniversary-of-yorktown.html) was here].)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't recall _to dub a knight_ as I wrote this, I could only think of _to knight_ - and I most likely wouldn't have seen the [connection](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dub). The thesaurus contains some of the religious terms I was also thinking of in French, for instance _baptiser_. But it sort of implies you have authority to baptize or name, whereas here or when M. le Marquis left the first time over with the _Victoire_, he didn't ask for the permission to leave from the king; he just left! If you attend hope you enjoy! Cheers!